# How to fix reversed arabic characters mixed with english in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I have a sql server database has table column contains arabic and english characters in the same field just like  `Oracle اوراكل`

Seeking your help to split the arabic characters from english ones to reverse them. as the arabic characters don't have a specific positions in the field, start, end or in the middle of field.

**Edit** The characters come from a legacy IBM mainframe application, and are stored in the wrong order, i.e. they are stored in the order they should be displayed left to right, instead of the order they are to be read.

What is needed is to make them display correctly in other applications.

Comment: Are you simply trying to display the text correctly? Or do you actually need to split the field up for some reason?

Comment: Hello Bin .. Thanks for your interests.Actually I am trying to display the text correctly only. As the Arabic characters are not displayed correctly, so am trying to reverse it.please advise

Comment: How are you displaying it currently?

Comment: `declare @v nvarchar(max)
set @v= N'This is a test. هذا هو الاختبار. This is a test.'
select @v`   Appears to display correctly to me. Does this work for you?

Comment: hello bin .. the issue is that data inserted in database like ' This is test رابتخلا وه اده' as you see Arabic characters are reversed and am requested to correct the display the Arabic characters without affecting the English characters to be like 'This is a test. هذا هو الاختبار' .. so i am asking for help.

Comment: How do you know they are inserted wrong - Perhaps it is just a display issue? It is important to know if they are stored wrongly or just displayed wrongly. You can check how it is stored by using `select substring(col, 1, 1), substring(col, 2, 1),substring(col, 3, 1),substring(col, 4, 1),substring(col, 5, 1)` to get the 1st to 5th characters and so on.

Comment: For example a string `test اختبار test` should be stored as `ItIeIsItI IاIخIتIبIاIرI ItIeIsItI` (ignore the I that is just to prevent adjacent Arabic characters) - so the storage is in the order you would read or write the characters, not the order the appear on screen. English from left to right, then move the hand to make space, and begin writing Arabic from right to left, then begin English left to right again.

Comment: Yes Bin .. but am not responsible for inserting data, am just selecting it and the external application inserts Arabic characters in reversing mode which is not readable .. all i want to do is to correct the displaying of it to be readable without affecting English ones.

Comment: Have you used the substring() I showed you go confirm that they are being inserted in the wrong order?  Maybe the external application is just displaying them wrong.

Comment: Actually, there is no specific positions for Arabic characters, may be start or end .. so Substring cannot be useful. i checked them in database.. they are displayed in wrong order.

Comment: You should pick the characters out one by one to *check if they are stored wrongly or correctly* not to reverse them etc. First ***check*** to make sure you have understood your problem correctly. I suspect it is stored correctly and just the display is wrong, that is why I am asking you to do a thorough check - I don't want you to mess up your data  by fixing the wrong problem.

Comment: OK nice simple solution for you :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you have a number of strings in the database which are, for legacy reasons, stored in non-lexical order. Probably they came from a character terminal based application which can only store characters in left-to-right order.

You can force compliant applications to display Arabic Left-to-Right by using the special Unicode character `LRO U+202D: LEFT-TO-RIGHT OVERRIDE`. This forces all characters to be rendered left to right regardless of how they normally would be rendered.

The effect ends at the end of the string or at character `PDF U+202C POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING`.

In your case all you need to do is put the LRO character at the beginning of every affected string:

```
select nchar(8237) + columnName as columnNameDisplay
from BadTable
```

The number 8237 the decimal equivalent of hexadecimal `202D`.

If you might be concatenating these strings with other strings which are stored correctly, you should also use the PDF character at the end:

```
select nchar(8237) + columnName + nchar(8236) as columnNameDisplay
from BadTable
```

This tells the text rendering engine that the forced Left-To-Right sequence has come to an end.

For more information see here:

- http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/#Explicit_Directional_Overrides

Notes:

- The combining characters will not combine properly
- Text-to-speech software won't work - it will probably read it alphabetically but I am not sure.

**Further Information**

Characters should be stored in the order they are written or read, not in the order they are displayed. So for example, the string:

```
test اختبار test
```

should be stored as

```
01  t
02  e
03  s
04  t
05   
07  ا
خ  08  
09  ت
10  ب  
11  ا
12  ر
13 
14  t
15  e
16  s
17  t
```

Notice that the leftmost Arabic character as displayed is stored at position 12 (`substring(@var, 12, 1)`), and the rightmost one as displayed is at position 7 (`substring(@var, 7, 1)`). If you simply count the positions characters as they are displayed from left to right, the Arabic portion appears reversed compared to how it is stored. But that is because that portion is supposed to be read from right to left, therefore it is displayed right to left.

To fix your problem you first need to check: Are the strings stored wrongly OR are they stored correctly but displayed wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

In oracle same solution is like:

```
select unistr('\202D') || columnName  as columnNameDisplay
from BadTable
```